# Search Service Property Returns Nothing

Tags: search, search-results, query

I'm using the SharePoint query web service to search and return results. Everything is working great and I'm able to get back plenty of properties from the search. Some of the properties include Title, Rank, Description, Filename, etc. One of the properties that I need is returning nothing. That property is the PictureThumbnailURL. If search within SharePoint then it works great, but as soon as I use the query web service then it returns nothing.

I also used the SharePoint Search Service Tool to execute my query and it also returns nothing for the PictureThumbnailURL. I believe this tool is also using the query web service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That property is mainly used when querying for Sites and Webs via contentClass with STS_Site or STS_Web to show the actual Icon as configured in the settings.

C:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

Is [This Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/173bece0-1fac-43c3-ad2d-ef796cc8371a) what you need? It seems to be the same issue, but I am not as familiar with this topic as others, so hopefully it will at least help you!

Comment: Unfortunately that's unrelated.